# How to stop kinematicbody walks whem released movement key?

Tags: godot

```
extends KinematicBody
var speed=10

var mouse_sensitivity=0.5
var direction=Vector3.ZERO
onready var head=$Head
func _ready():
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_cancel"):
        Input.set_mouse_mode(Input.MOUSE_MODE_CAPTURED)
func _input(event):
    if event is InputEventMouseMotion:
        rotate_y(deg2rad(-event.relative.x*mouse_sensitivity))
        head.rotate_x(deg2rad(-event.relative.y*mouse_sensitivity))
        head.rotation.x=clamp(head.rotation.x,deg2rad(-90),deg2rad(90))
func _process(delta):
    Vector3.ZERO
    if Input.is_action_pressed("mf"):
        direction-=transform.basis.z
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("b"):
        direction+=transform.basis.z
    direction=direction.normalized()
    move_and_slide(direction*speed,Vector3.UP)
```

I don't know what i'm doing wrong.
My kinematicBody keeps moving after released a key.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to `direction`:

```
var direction=Vector3.ZERO

# ...

func _process(delta):
    Vector3.ZERO
    if Input.is_action_pressed("mf"):
        direction-=transform.basis.z
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("b"):
        direction+=transform.basis.z
    direction=direction.normalized()
    move_and_slide(direction*speed,Vector3.UP)
```

It starts as `ZERO`. Then you press one of the recognized inputs, and you modify it. It is no longer `ZERO` after than input.

Of course, subsequent executions of `_process` would not enter the branches where you modify `direction`. However, `direction` retained its value.

This line will run regardless of input:

```
move_and_slide(direction*speed,Vector3.UP)
```

It does not move when `direction` is `ZERO`. But again, after the first input `direction` is not `ZERO` anymore.

---

I believe you meant to write `direction = Vector3.ZERO` as the first line of `_process`.

I remind you to pay attention to your warnings:

- You are not using `delta`. May mean the code does not compensate for variations in frame rate.
- You a standalone expression (`Vector3.ZERO`). That does nothing. Did you meant to do something there?
- You are discarding the return value of `move_and_slide`. *To be honest, I usually tell Godot to ignore this one.*

It is a good sign to have your script without warnings. Review them. And if you decide that there is nothing wrong, you can tell Godot to ignore them (this can be done done with a comment `# warning-ignore:...`. See [GDScript warning system](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/scripting/gdscript/warning_system.html)). Telling Godot to ignore warnings will make it easier to notice when a new warning pops up.

---

Something else, I believe this code should be in `_physics_process`. This is from [`move_and_slide` documentation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_kinematicbody.html#class-kinematicbody-method-move-and-slide):

> This method should be used in Node._physics_process (or in a method called by Node._physics_process), as it uses the physics step's delta value automatically in calculations. Otherwise, the simulation will run at an incorrect speed.

Comment: Thanks, I thought _process was the same as _physics_process and I tryed deleting _physics but it don't works for my.